# How to make an always in bottom item in html and css

Tags: css

Edited: I was trying to make a chat page that has a message textbox and a button to send inside a form element. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>A</title>
        <style>
            body{height: 100vh;}
            form{
                line-height: 40px;
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

<body>
        <form name="form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="A message goes here"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <script>
            var search = window.screen.height - 40;
            document.form.style.top = search + "px";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the form goes more than 100vh

Comment: think you need to show an actual example...anyways no need for js...you just need to add flex to it..

Comment: You mean display:flex;

Comment: @Riskbreaker I tried but It didn't work

Comment: yep just add that on that on content container (I assume you have one...)...hence this is why you should do a example code to see your whole code

Comment: @Riskbreaker this

Comment: @Riskbreaker https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1LCPGOGMEQU

Comment: where is your content you mentioned height:680px ?

Comment: My device height is 640px but it display my webpage 680px

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for js or absolute positioning...you just need to set it up the way you need to look at it ...when I said use `display: flex` that needs to be inputed in the container box and your web content should go on a separate section outside your form like so:

```
  body {height: 100%}

  .container {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .content {flex: 1;}

   form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #000;
  }
```

I copy your code and added it here: https://codepen.io/izzy_zeke/pen/OqVOVL